# XPath/XSLT: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first sort key

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

Hello stackoverflow community,

I am trying to order by a nested attribute, but keep getting an error saying that

> XPTY0004: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first sort key.

This specifically occurs in the line

```
order by $x/role/@startdate
```

from the following code

```
<result>{
  for $x in /congress/people/person
  where $x/role[@type = 'sen' and @current = 1 and @state = 'NC']
  order by $x/role/@startdate
  return <senator name="{$x/@name}"/>
 }</result>
```

I am wondering how you appropriately order by the nested attribute.

Edit:

Here is some sample code of the XML document

```
<congress>
  <people>
    <person birthday="1952-11-09" gender="M" id="B000944" name="Sherrod Brown">
      <role district="13" enddate="1995-01-03" party="Democrat" startdate="1993-01-05" state="OH" type="rep"/>
      <role district="13" enddate="1997-01-03" party="Democrat" startdate="1995-01-04" state="OH" type="rep"/>
      <role enddate="2007-01-03" party="Democrat" startdate="2001-01-03" state="WA" type="sen"/>
      <role enddate="2013-01-03" party="Democrat" startdate="2007-01-04" state="WA" type="sen"/>
      <role current="1" enddate="2019-01-03" party="Democrat" startdate="2013-01-03" state="WA" type="sen"/>
    </person>
    <person>
      ...
    </person>
  </people>
</congress>
```

Comment: If you want to select the attribute node you need to use `$x/role/@startdate`. Even then, if there several `role` elements with that attribute, you will get that error. Show us the input sample and explain which attribute you want to select if there are several. XQuery 3.1 has a `sort` function where you could get away with `sort(/congress/people/person[role[@type = 'sen' and @current = 1 and @state = 'NC']], (), function($p) { $p/role/@startdate })` to sort on all attributes.

Comment: You would need to use a particular `role`'s `startdate` attribute (e.g. `$x/role[1]/@startdate` or `$x/role[@current = 1]/@startdate`) or you indeed need that `sort` function.

Comment: *"...so, by which `role/@startdate` do you want to sort, respectively?"* is the question the error message is asking. The first role for each person? The last? The one with the highest `@startdate`? (that's not necessarily the same as "the last") The "current" role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
for $x in /congress/people/person
  where $x/role[@type = 'sen' and @current = 1 and @state = 'NC']
  order by $x/role/@startdate
```

I suspect (though I'm guessing) that you want to sort by the `@startdate` of the `role` that matches the `where` condition. If you're confident that there's exactly one such role, then you could write

```
for $x in /congress/people/person
let $role := $x/role[@type = 'sen' and @current = 1 and @state = 'NC']
where exists($role)
order by $role/@startdate
```

If there's any possibility that more than one role satisfies the predicate, then you still need to somehow indicate which of those role's start-dates you want to sort by.

Comment: Would it not be easier to use `for $r in /congress/people/person/role[@type = 'sen' and @current = 1 and @state = 'NC']` in this case and from there `select` the parent node? This would resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I appreciate the helpful comments from everyone!